# I dont understand this javascript function absolute();

Tags: javascript, computer-science

```
    function absolute(number)
    {
    if (number < 0)
        return -number;
    else
        return number;
    }

   console.log(absolute(-144));
```

prints on console: 144

If(number < 0) then it returns -number. So therefore -144 is less then 0 so it should return -144 , not 144 correct? if its not less then number , then it should be positive number.

This is what i am understanding but its printing 144 on console.

Comment: Your problem has to do with Math, not with programming. -(-144) is 144.

Comment: I don't understand this function either, as the javascript math object already has a perfectly usable abs() function.

Comment: Thank you!that makes sense. I did not know that it actually looks like this (-)(number); Now i see.

Comment: @EikePierstorff, I can see a NIH syndrome ! Quick, where is the antidote ?! ;)

Comment: @EikePierstorff i understand i can use that as well. But im learning javascript. In the early chapters, book has not introduced it to me yet.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `absolute()` function returns the *absolute* value of the number.

```
-144 => 144
0 => 0
42 => 42
```

You're overthinking it ;)

Easy steps:

1. Number is negative ( < 0)
2. We want the absolute value, same value without the sign
3. So we remove the minus by applying another minus to it
4. Get the absolute value and rule the world